# How can I compute a SHA-2 (ideally SHA 256 or SHA 512) hash in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, security, hash, sha256

The Security services API doesn't appear to allow me to compute a hash directly. There are plenty of public domain and liberally licensed versions available, but I'd rather use a system library implementation if possible.

The data is accessible via NSData, or plain pointers.

The cryptographic strength of the hash is important to me. SHA-256 is the minimum acceptable hash size.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is what I'm using for SHA1:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

+ (NSData *)sha1:(NSData *)data {
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if ( CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hash) ) {
        NSData *sha1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];        
        return sha1;
    }
return nil;
}
```

Replace `CC_SHA1` with `CC_SHA256` (or whichever you need), as well as `CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH` with `CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH`.

Comment: This didn't work.. converting the returned data to an NSString returned nil for me. The post below "hashed_string" worked if I passed in the data.

Comment: @TheJeff - The question doesn't say anything about returning the SHA value as a hexadecimal string. Converting `NSData` to `NSString` can be a separate question on its own.

Comment: @alex-i, you are right, the NSData comes back, however the conversion to string I was mentioning does not work - you have to use the method that EgeAkpinar proposed below. I'm still curious what and how that works, however like you said that isn't the purpose of this post.

Comment: Swift version for this?

Answer (score 35):

Here's a pretty similar one based on NSString

```
+ (NSString *)hashed_string:(NSString *)input
{
    const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    // This is an iOS5-specific method.
    // It takes in the data, how much data, and then output format, which in this case is an int array.
    CC_SHA256(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    // Parse through the CC_SHA256 results (stored inside of digest[]).
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    }

    return output;
}
```

(Credits go to http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: for iOS 7+ you to cast the data.length: CC_SHA256(data.bytes, (int)data.length, digest);

Comment: data should be `[NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:strlen(cstr)];`
It'd be better to use `[input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me

```
func sha256(securityString : String) -> String {
    let data = securityString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var hash = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &hash)
    let output = NSMutableString(capacity: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    for byte in hash {
        output.appendFormat("%02x", byte)
    }
    return output as String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below link i used for creating document hash value and Its very simple and easy to  calculate hash value specially for large files.

Link : http://www.joel.lopes-da-silva.com/2010/09/07/compute-md5-or-sha-hash-of-large-file-efficiently-on-ios-and-mac-os-x/comment-page-1/#comment-18533

Comment: External links may disappear over time. Please include a self-contained piece of code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSData *)sha256DataFromData:(NSData *)data {
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256([data bytes], (int)[data length], result);
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:result length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up https://stackoverflow.com/a/13199111/1254812 a bit and structured it as an `NSString` extension

```
@interface NSString (SHA2HEX)

/*
 Get the SHA2 (256 bit) digest as a hex string.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* sha2hex;
@end

@implementation NSString (SHA2HEX)

- (NSString*)sha2hex
{
    NSData *data = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (data.length > UINT32_MAX)
        return nil;

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, digest);

    const int hexlen = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2;
    NSMutableString *hexstr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:hexlen];

    for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [hexstr appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    }

    return hexstr;
}

@end
```