# SHA256 in swift

Tags: swift, sha256

I want to use sha256 in my project, but I had some troubles rewriting objC code to swift code. Help me please. I used this answer: [How can I compute a SHA-2 (ideally SHA 256 or SHA 512) hash in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228092/how-can-i-compute-a-sha-2-ideally-sha-256-or-sha-512-hash-in-ios)

Here's my code

```
var hash : [CUnsignedChar]
CC_SHA256(data.bytes, data.length, hash)
var res : NSData = NSData.dataWithBytes(hash, length: CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
```

it gives me error everything because swift cannot convert `Int` to `CC_LONG`, for example.

Comment: You can call ObjectiveC methods from swift directly, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Questions about translating from one language to another are off topic? Since when?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum problem is in string "unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];"

Comment: @ЮрикАлександров `CUnsignedChar[]` ?

Comment: the other problem is that Int do not convertible to CC_LONG

Comment: @ЮрикАлександров please add this extra info to your question above, and clearly describe your problem. Help us help you.

Comment: @AlexWayne that's my code: var hash : [CUnsignedChar]
        CC_SHA256(data.bytes, data.length, hash)
        var res : NSData = NSData.dataWithBytes(hash, length: CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        it gives me error everything because swift cannot convert Int to CC_LONG, for example.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You have to convert explicitly between `Int` and `CC_LONG`, because Swift does not
do implicit conversions, as in (Objective-)C.

You also have to define `hash` as an array of the required size.

```
func sha256(data : NSData) -> NSData {
    var hash = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &hash)
    let res = NSData(bytes: hash, length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    return res
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `NSMutableData` to allocate the needed buffer:

```
func sha256(data : NSData) -> NSData {
    let res = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), UnsafeMutablePointer(res.mutableBytes))
    return res
}
```

**Update for Swift 3 and 4:**

```
func sha256(data : Data) -> Data {
    var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &hash)
    }
    return Data(bytes: hash)
}
```

**Update for Swift 5:**

```
func sha256(data : Data) -> Data {
    var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &hash)
    }
    return Data(hash)
}
```

Comment: how can i convert this nsdata to string as it is when i am trying to convert its give me wrong value

Comment: Great answer! Just FYI API is now repeatElement... instead of repeating... on Int as of Xcode 8.2.1 for those coming across this more recently.

Comment: @iOSGamer: I double-checked that the Swift 3 version above is correct and compiles in Xcode 8.2.1 :)

Comment: @MartinR So I double-checked and indeed even though it didn't show up in autocompletion it does exist, compiles and works. Being a newbie, a defer to your version. Sorry for the noise, and thanks once again!

Comment: As an addition to this solution, to make `CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH`, `CC_SHA256`, and `CC_LONG`work in Swift, you have to add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>` to the bridging header file.

Comment: Your Swift 5 example is out of date.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: What is the problem? It compiles and runs in my Xcode 10.2 with Swift 5.

Comment: Ok, it works if you do exactly as you wrote it. Xcode seems to have some issues with the `$0.baseAddress` part at random. I think it depends on how it infers the other arguments. If it can't infer the type to be UInt8 for the pointer, you can't access the `.baseAddress` property. (If you say, used a `Data` pointer instead of `[UInt8]`.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: Yes, for the other argument you would have to bind the raw data pointer to an UInt8 pointer. Passing the address of an array is easier. It has been suggested to improve the interoperability with C functions, compare https://forums.swift.org/t/withunsafebytes-data-api-confusion/22142/16.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I have tested on Xcode 11.3.1 and Martins solution worked fine. I confirm it wont work in Xcode 11.

Answer (score 110):

Updated for Swift 5.

Put this extension somewhere in your project and use it on a string like this: mystring.sha256(), or on data with data.sha256()

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

extension Data{
    public func sha256() -> String{
        return hexStringFromData(input: digest(input: self as NSData))
    }
    
    private func digest(input : NSData) -> NSData {
        let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)
        CC_SHA256(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
        return NSData(bytes: hash, length: digestLength)
    }
    
    private  func hexStringFromData(input: NSData) -> String {
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: input.length)
        input.getBytes(&bytes, length: input.length)
        
        var hexString = ""
        for byte in bytes {
            hexString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
        }
        
        return hexString
    }
}

public extension String {
    func sha256() -> String{
        if let stringData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return stringData.sha256()
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm @Andi. Only one correction that Xcode wants:  
This line:  
`return hexStringFromData(input: digest(input: stringData))`  
Change by:  
`return hexStringFromData(input: digest(input: stringData as NSData))`

Comment: Can add this extension into Framework Project? How can create Objective-C Bridging Header into Framework Project ?

Comment: Can I use this function to NSData instance?
`let data =  NSData(contentsOfFile: "/Users/danila/metaprogramming-ruby-2.pdf")
data.sha256()
`

Comment: This one is a life sawer, literally.

Answer (score 71):

With `CryptoKit` added in iOS13, we now have native Swift API:

```swift
import Foundation
import CryptoKit

// CryptoKit.Digest utils
extension Digest {
    var bytes: [UInt8] { Array(makeIterator()) }
    var data: Data { Data(bytes) }

    var hexStr: String {
        bytes.map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
    }
}

func example() {
    guard let data = "hello world".data(using: .utf8) else { return }
    let digest = SHA256.hash(data: data)
    print(digest.data) // 32 bytes
    print(digest.hexStr) // B94D27B9934D3E08A52E52D7DA7DABFAC484EFE37A5380EE9088F7ACE2EFCDE9
}
```

Because utils are defined for protocol `Digest`, you can use it for all digest type in `CryptoKit`, like `SHA384Digest`, `SHA512Digest`, `SHA1Digest`, `MD5Digest`...

Comment: Good answer, but this needs the target version to be mni 10 iOS13.
I had to use both this solution and manual computing depending on iOS version.

Comment: Any differences? `var hexString: String {
        self.map {
            String(format: "%02hhx", $0)
        }.joined()
    }`

Comment: The solution does work, but it is impossible to compile in Release configuration with target lower than iOS 11 because of this issue in Xcode: http://openradar.appspot.com/7495817

Comment: Excellent, concise answer. Works in MacOS 11 CLI app.

Comment: So, just to confirm I'm not crazy - Digest is happy to calculate the hex string into the debug description (with extraneous text preventing it from being immediately usable) - but to get the hex string alone, you have to extend the class manually?

Comment: Works in Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 18):

Functions giving the SHA from `NSData` & `String` (Swift 3):

```
func sha256(_ data: Data) -> Data? {
    guard let res = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)) else { return nil }
    CC_SHA256((data as NSData).bytes, CC_LONG(data.count), res.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
    return res as Data
}

func sha256(_ str: String) -> String? {
    guard
        let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let shaData = sha256(data)
        else { return nil }
    let rc = shaData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    return rc
}
```

Include in your bridging header:

```
#import "CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
```

Comment: I got this error on this portion [let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)] -> Error : Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'String'. My I please know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Did you add to the bridging header? This code builds for me unchanged from Swift 3-ish to 4.1. (Xcode 9.3 builds for me).

Comment: This does not give a correct Hash. Check with an online SHA generator to see for yourself.

Comment: Perhaps your online generators perform the operation including a terminating zero? Are you checking an online SHA256, or maybe SHA-1 or SHA-2?

Answer (score 17):

I researched many answers and I summarized it:

```
import CryptoKit
import CommonCrypto
```

```
extension String {
    func hash256() -> String {
        let inputData = Data(utf8)
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let hashed = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
            return hashed.compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        } else {
            var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
            inputData.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
                _ = CC_SHA256(bytes.baseAddress, UInt32(inputData.count), &digest)
            }
            return digest.makeIterator().compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

A version for Swift 5 that uses CryptoKit on iOS 13 and falls back to CommonCrypto otherwise:

```swift
import CommonCrypto
import CryptoKit
import Foundation

private func hexString(_ iterator: Array<UInt8>.Iterator) -> String {
    return iterator.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
}

extension Data {

    public var sha256: String {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return hexString(SHA256.hash(data: self).makeIterator())
        } else {
            var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
            self.withUnsafeBytes { bytes in
                _ = CC_SHA256(bytes.baseAddress, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
            }
            return hexString(digest.makeIterator())
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
let hexDigest = string.data(using: .ascii)!.sha256
assert(hexDigest == "d7a8fbb307d7809469ca9abcb0082e4f8d5651e46d3cdb762d02d0bf37c9e592")
```

Also available via Swift package manager:
https://github.com/ralfebert/TinyHashes

Comment: Won't the `import CryptoKit` break on iOS 12 though? It's an iOS 13.0+ only framework.

Comment: @KevinRenskers Use can use `#if canImport(CryptoKit)` for conditional import.
Don't forget to set set `-weak_framework CryptoKit` in `Other Linker Flags`

Comment: Not working for me on iOS12 and below, I followed the above suggestion but I'm still getting "Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoKit.framework/CryptoKit" when the app starts.

Answer (score 9):

```
import CommonCrypto

public extension String {

  var sha256: String {
      let data = Data(utf8)
      var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

      data.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
          _ = CC_SHA256(buffer.baseAddress, CC_LONG(buffer.count), &hash)
      }

      return hash.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to have backward compatibility this is will works. Importing CryptoKit as the other solutions suggest, will crash the app on iOS12 and below with this error "Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoKit.framework/CryptoKit" when the app starts.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my simple 3-line Swift 4 function for this using the Security Transforms API, which is part of Foundation on macOS. (Unfortunately iOS programmers cannot use this technique.)

```
import Foundation

extension Data {
    public func sha256Hash() -> Data {
        let transform = SecDigestTransformCreate(kSecDigestSHA2, 256, nil)
        SecTransformSetAttribute(transform, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, self as CFTypeRef, nil)
        return SecTransformExecute(transform, nil) as! Data
    }
}
```

Comment: This looked great until I saw no iOS love.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that uses the CoreFoundation Security Transforms API, so you don't even need to link to CommonCrypto.  For some reason in 10.10/Xcode 7 linking to CommmonCrypto with Swift is drama so I used this instead.

This method reads from an `NSInputStream`, which you can either get from a file, or you can make one that reads an `NSData`, or you can make bound reader/writer streams for a buffered process.

```
// digestType is from SecDigestTransform and would be kSecDigestSHA2, etc 
func digestForStream(stream : NSInputStream,
    digestType type : CFStringRef, length : Int) throws -> NSData {

    let transform = SecTransformCreateGroupTransform().takeRetainedValue()

    let readXform = SecTransformCreateReadTransformWithReadStream(stream as CFReadStreamRef).takeRetainedValue()

    var error : Unmanaged<CFErrorRef>? = nil

    let digestXform : SecTransformRef = try {
        let d = SecDigestTransformCreate(type, length, &error)
        if d == nil {
            throw error!.takeUnretainedValue()
        } else {
            return d.takeRetainedValue()
        }
    }()

    SecTransformConnectTransforms(readXform, kSecTransformOutputAttributeName,
        digestXform, kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
        transform, &error)
    if let e = error { throw e.takeUnretainedValue() }

    if let output = SecTransformExecute(transform, &error) as? NSData {
        return output
    } else {
        throw error!.takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand this is only available on OSX, not iOS.

Answer (score 4):

**Tested in Swift5.**

In case you want to get the hash **in String**,

this is how I did.

```
private func getHash(_ phrase:String) -> String{
    let data = phrase.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let length = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
    }
    return digest.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined(separator: "")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 5:

```
guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    var sha256 = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    sha256.withUnsafeMutableBytes { sha256Buffer in
        data.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
            let _ = CC_SHA256(buffer.baseAddress!, CC_LONG(buffer.count), sha256Buffer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress)
        }
    }

    return sha256
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers will have performance problems for calculating digests from large amounts of data (e.g. large files). You will not want to load all data into memory at once. Consider the following approach using update/finalize:

```
final class SHA256Digest {

    enum InputStreamError: Error {
        case createFailed(URL)
        case readFailed
    }

    private lazy var context: CC_SHA256_CTX = {
        var shaContext = CC_SHA256_CTX()
        CC_SHA256_Init(&shaContext)
        return shaContext
    }()
    private var result: Data? = nil

    init() {
    }

    func update(url: URL) throws {
        guard let inputStream = InputStream(url: url) else {
            throw InputStreamError.createFailed(url)
        }
        return try update(inputStream: inputStream)
    }

    func update(inputStream: InputStream) throws {
        guard result == nil else {
            return
        }
        inputStream.open()
        defer {
            inputStream.close()
        }
        let bufferSize = 4096
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        defer {
            buffer.deallocate()
        }
        while true {
            let bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if bytesRead < 0 {
                //Stream error occured
                throw (inputStream.streamError ?? InputStreamError.readFailed)
            } else if bytesRead == 0 {
                //EOF
                break
            }
            self.update(bytes: buffer, length: bytesRead)
        }
    }

    func update(data: Data) {
        guard result == nil else {
            return
        }
        data.withUnsafeBytes {
            self.update(bytes: $0, length: data.count)
        }
    }

    func update(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer, length: Int) {
        guard result == nil else {
            return
        }
        _ = CC_SHA256_Update(&self.context, bytes, CC_LONG(length))
    }

    func finalize() -> Data {
        if let calculatedResult = result {
            return calculatedResult
        }
        var resultBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        CC_SHA256_Final(&resultBuffer, &self.context)
        let theResult = Data(bytes: resultBuffer)
        result = theResult
        return theResult
    }
}

extension Data {

    private static let hexCharacterLookupTable: [Character] = [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f"
    ]

    var hexString: String {
        return self.reduce(into: String(), { (result, byte) in
            let c1: Character = Data.hexCharacterLookupTable[Int(byte >> 4)]
            let c2: Character = Data.hexCharacterLookupTable[Int(byte & 0x0F)]
            result.append(c1)
            result.append(c2)
        })
    }
}
```

You could use it as follows:

```
let digest = SHA256Digest()
try digest.update(url: fileURL)
let result = digest.finalize().hexString
print(result)
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for! It was sadly incompatible with Swift 5, but with a few simple fixes it worked: https://gist.github.com/yspreen/95627d72bedcd47f1c0d29271b5600ea

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use:

```
extension String {
    var sha256:String? {
        guard let stringData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return nil }
        return digest(input: stringData as NSData).base64EncodedString(options: [])
    }

    private func digest(input : NSData) -> NSData {
        let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)
        CC_SHA256(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
        return NSData(bytes: hash, length: digestLength)
    }
}
```

The hasded String is base64 encoded.