# Cannot invoke initializer for type UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>

Tags: ios, swift, hash, swift3, sha256

I'm trying to convert my string into SHA256 hash, but I get the next error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'
```

That's my function:

```
func SHA256(data: String) -> Data {
    var hash = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))!

    if let newData: Data = data.data(using: .utf8) {
        let bytes = newData.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> Void in
            CC_SHA256(bytes, CC_LONG(newData.length), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(hash.mutableBytes))
        }
    }

    return hash as Data
}
```

so, for this part

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(hash.mutableBytes)
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'
```

How can I fix that and what I do wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388747/sha256-in-swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better use `Data` also for the result `hash`.

In Swift 3, `withUnsafePointer(_:)` and `withUnsafeMutablePointer(:_)` are generic types and Swift can infer the Pointee types correctly when used with "well-formed" closures, which means you have no need to convert Pointee types manually.

[func withUnsafeBytes((UnsafePointer) -> ResultType)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes)

[func withUnsafeMutableBytes((UnsafeMutablePointer) -> ResultType)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779823-withunsafemutablebytes)

```
func SHA256(data: String) -> Data {
    var hash = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    if let newData: Data = data.data(using: .utf8) {
        _ = hash.withUnsafeMutableBytes {mutableBytes in
            newData.withUnsafeBytes {bytes in
                CC_SHA256(bytes, CC_LONG(newData.count), mutableBytes)
            }
        }
    }

    return hash
}
```

In Swift 3, the initializers of `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer`, which was used to convert Pointee types till Swift 2, are removed. But in many cases, you can work without type conversions of pointers.

Comment: I get an error: `NSMutableData has no member hash.withUnsafeMutableBytes`

Comment: @Doe, please see whole code I have shown, especially the line `var hash = ...`.

Comment: why when I print my hash it pribts only `32 bytes`, but not the hash string?

Comment: @Doe, the content is exactly the same as when using `NSData` or `NSMutableData`. If you want to see the content for debugging purpose, you may need to write something like `print(hash as NSData)`.

Comment: I want to get my hash value of that string. For example in web it returns you string, like `e0712cc9db510dd3611bc3...`, but here it gives me `<2c6e991d c60e6e06 c3d562c1 c6f47425 2b50b3b1...>` is it the same thing?

Comment: @Doe, `Data` (or `NSData`) is just a collection of bytes and `<2c6e...>` is an old plist-format representation of the content. If you need a specific hexadecimal representation, you need to generate it by yourself. Even if you use `NSMutableData`, you cannot get it automatically. For example, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39075044/6541007).

Comment: Thank you for your help!