# Creating SHA256 hash with swift4

Tags: sha256, xcode9, swift4

I've done some looking around but i've only been able to find examples that use Objective-C to create SHA256 hashes. Is there a way to do this with only Swift4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHA256 in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388747/sha256-in-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
func ccSha256(data: Data) -> Data {
    var digest = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    _ = digest.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (digestBytes) in
        data.withUnsafeBytes { (stringBytes) in
            CC_SHA256(stringBytes, CC_LONG(data.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }
    return digest
}
```

You can call like this :

```
let str = "givesomestringtoencode"
let data = ccSha256(data: str.data(using: .utf8)!)
print("sha256 String: \(data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())")
```

Add the below in bridging header file:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
```

Comment: When I add the function to my code, it gives me multiple errors

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You have import `CommonCrypto` in your bridging header.