# Can't convert withUnsafeBytes to non-deprecated code with SHA-256

Tags: swift, deprecated, sha256

I had an issue before with the `withUnsafeBytes` method on `Data` being deprecated. I managed to get it working with the newer method for using SHA-512.

I recently encountered the same issue again and tried to re-use the same solution as before but changed the SHA-512 to SHA-256 but it didn't decode the data into a string correctly

Here is what I have as me trying to see if it will work:

```
let rsa2048Asn1Header:[UInt8] = [
        0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0x22, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
        0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x82, 0x01, 0x0f, 0x00
    ]

func sha256(data: Data) -> String {
        var keyWithHeader = data// Data(rsa2048Asn1Header)
        keyWithHeader.append(data)

        var hash: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>! = nil/// [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

        var result = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        _ = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes({ resultBytes in
            hash = resultBytes.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
            keyWithHeader.withUnsafeBytes({ stringBytes in
                let sBytes = resultBytes.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
                CC_SHA256(sBytes, CC_LONG(keyWithHeader.count), hash)
        })

        let string = String(cString: hash)
        return string.data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
}
```

but the string it creates is completely wrong and not the same as using the deprecated method:

```
var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))

        keyWithHeader.withUnsafeBytes {
            _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(keyWithHeader.count), &hash)
        }
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong because it was working when I used this code with SHA-512

Comment: Possibly helpful: the Swift 5 updates in https://stackoverflow.com/q/25388747/1187415.

Comment: The accepted answer in that is what's giving the deprecation warning :(

Comment: That is strange: the “Update for Swift 5” version in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391020/1187415 compiles without warnings in my Xcode 11.2

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with input data, actual output, and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use the updated `CryptoKit`

```
import CommonCrypto

func cryptoSHA256(data : Data) -> String {
    let hash = SHA256.hash(data: keyWithHeader)
    return Data(hash).base64EncodedString()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also in the Q&A that I mentioned above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255549/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58416034/1187415.