# Swift / Apple Sign In - Type HASH256 has no member hash

Tags: swift, firebase

Issue: "Type HASH256 has no member hash"

Background: Trying to implement Apple sign in with Firebase on Swift

Tried to resolve the issue with the following:
-all pods update
-import CommonCrypto + import CryptoKit
-clean build folder / build

The error is still present

```
// Adapted from https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/nonce#generate-a-cryptographically-random-nonce
    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
      precondition(length > 0)
      let charset: Array<Character> =
          Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
      var result = ""
      var remainingLength = length

      while remainingLength > 0 {
        let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
          var random: UInt8 = 0
          let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
          if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
            fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
          }
          return random
        }

        randoms.forEach { random in
          if length == 0 {
            return
          }

          if random < charset.count {
            result.append(charset[Int(random)])
            remainingLength -= 1
          }
        }
      }

      return result
    }

    //Start Apple's sign-in flow
    // Unhashed nonce.
    fileprivate var currentNonce: String?

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    func startSignInWithAppleFlow() {
      let nonce = randomNonceString()
      currentNonce = nonce
      let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
      let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
      request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
      request.nonce = sha256(nonce)

      let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self as! ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self as! ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding
      authorizationController.performRequests()
    }

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
      let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
    let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
      let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        return String(format: "%02x", $0)
      }.joined()

      return hashString
    }



//    func SHA256() -> String {
//
//        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
//        let res = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
//        CC_SHA256(((data! as NSData)).bytes, CC_LONG(data!.count), res?.mutableBytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self))
//        let hashedString = "\(res!)".replacingOccurrences(of: "", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
//        let badchar: CharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\"<\",\">\"")
//        let cleanedstring: String = (hashedString.components(separatedBy: badchar) as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "")
//        return cleanedstring
//
//    }


}

//Apple extension
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension AuthViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
      guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
        fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
      }
      guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
        print("Unable to fetch identity token")
        return
      }
      guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
        print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
        return
      }
      // Initialize a Firebase credential.
      let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                                idToken: idTokenString,
                                                accessToken: nonce)
      // Sign in with Firebase.
      Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
          // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
          // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
          // your request to Apple.
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
          return
        }
        // User is signed in to Firebase with Apple.
        // ...
      }
    }
  }

  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // Handle error.
    print("Sign in with Apple errored: \(error)")
  }

}
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwNg0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, I spend two days figured it out!

The reason is we mistaken installed 'CryptoKit' in our Podfile. which apple also has a build-in 'CryptoKit' for iOS version 13+. 
Solution :

1.deleted pod ''CryptoKit' in our pod file.
2. pod install

after that, we will use apple build in 'CryptoKit' which has the build-in method hash.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: add this outside of your class and then instead of `request.nonce = sha256(nonce)`, type `request.nonce = nonce.sha256()`

```
extension String {

    func sha256() -> String{
        if let stringData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return hexStringFromData(input: digest(input: stringData as NSData))
        }
        return ""
    }

    private func digest(input : NSData) -> NSData {
        let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: digestLength)
        CC_SHA256(input.bytes, UInt32(input.length), &hash)
        return NSData(bytes: hash, length: digestLength)
    }

    private  func hexStringFromData(input: NSData) -> String {
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: input.length)
        input.getBytes(&bytes, length: input.length)
        var hexString = ""
        for byte in bytes {
            hexString += String(format:"%02x", UInt8(byte))
        }
        return hexString
    }
}
```

[credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788437/6481734)