# How to deal with `withUnsafeBytes` is deprecated warning?

Tags: swift, deprecated, sha256

I am getting deprecated warning for below code,

```
_ = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    _ = CC_SHA256($0, CC_LONG(data.count), &digest)
}
```

> 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

How can I deal with this?

### Update

As suggested by Martin, I used below [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391020/1084174) for Swift-5,

```
func sha256(data : Data) -> Data {
    var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &hash)
    }
    return Data(hash)
}
```

That's even giving comilers error,

> Value of type 'UnsafePointer<_>' has no member 'baseAddress'

### Update2

[Martins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391020/1084174) works fine in Xcode 11.3.1. It does not work in Xcode 11 though.

Comment: The warning literally tells you which function you should use instead

Comment: I am not sure what `<R>` means in the suggested signature, So I asked for help. @mag_zbc

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25388747/1187415 (with various Swift 5 solutions).

Comment: @MartinR, I am getting the compilers error `Value of type 'UnsafePointer<_>' has no member 'baseAddress'` as commented by Claus Jørgensen in your referred answer for Swift-5.

Comment: That is strange. I just double-checked that the code compiles with the current Xcode 11.3.1. Can you try it in a new fresh project?

Comment: @MartinR Your solution works perfectly in Xcode 11.3.1, I was trying with Xcode 11 before. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r)'s solutions worked fine for `Xcode 11.3.1+`,

```
func sha256(data : Data) -> Data {
    var hash = [UInt8](repeating: 0,  count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    data.withUnsafeBytes {
        _ = CC_SHA256($0.baseAddress, CC_LONG(data.count), &hash)
    }
    return Data(hash)
}
```